# HTTP/HTTPS Proxy

Tags: http, https, proxy

Tell me, please, a good HTTP/HTTPS proxy with the ability to analyze the response from the target resource, and if the response of the target resource does not match the right one, the proxy returns a custom response.

Comment: As written, this isn't a really question about programming. It might be helpful for you to explain your larger task-- are you trying to build a program that does something? How would you "match" the "right one"? Etc.

Comment: Here, the question is more about getting a consultation, whether there are ready-made tested solutions, or still write your own proxy implementation for a specific task. Maybe it makes no sense to spend time on their own implementation and the community will prompt the available solutions.

Comment: StackOverflow explicitly is not designed to ask questions of that nature (they're considered off-topic). That's why I can't suggest you use [Fiddler](https://fiddler2.com), for instance.